# SQL Oracle: Query of showing two columns from two tables as one and counting into numeric value

Tags: sql, oracle

The query is:

I have a member table and a stage table, the 'band_name' is the foreign key in the members table.

I need to show the stage name (stage_name) and how many members will be performing on each stage.

I have attempted so far the following:

```
SELECT stage_name, member_ID,member.band_name
  FROM stage, member
 WHERE stage.stage_name = member.band_name
 ORDER BY stage_name, member.band_name, member_ID;
```

This shows one stage_name and the three members but NOT as a number e.g.3 and none of the other stage_names

I think I may need to use COUNT and maybe also INNER join?

FYI - I am very new to SQL oracle

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  Commas are history.  `JOIN` is not only the future, but the present and much of the past as well.

Then, you want `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT stage_name, COUNT(m.member_ID)
FROM stage s LEFT JOIN
     member m 
     ON s.stage_name = m.band_name
GROUP BY s.stage_name 
ORDER BY s.stage_name;
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response. Do you recommend any specific sites to learn SQL Oracle? As so far I've been watching old YouTube videos hence the commas.

Comment: @NLearner . . . Only when asked do I point I that I have written books on this subject.

Comment: Thank you! I will defiantly be reading the books you have written